# Solving XOR with 3 data points using Multi-Layered Perceptron

Tags: numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, xor, perceptron

The XOR problem is known to be solved by the multi-layer perceptron given all 4 boolean inputs and outputs, it trains and memorizes the weights needed to reproduce the I/O. E.g.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

def sigmoid(x): # Returns values that sums to one.
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(sx):
    # See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1225116
    return sx * (1 - sx)

# Cost functions.
def cost(predicted, truth):
    return truth - predicted

xor_input = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
xor_output = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

X = xor_input
Y = xor_output

# Define the shape of the weight vector.
num_data, input_dim = X.shape
# Lets set the dimensions for the intermediate layer.
hidden_dim = 5
# Initialize weights between the input layers and the hidden layer.
W1 = np.random.random((input_dim, hidden_dim))

# Define the shape of the output vector. 
output_dim = len(Y.T)
# Initialize weights between the hidden layers and the output layer.
W2 = np.random.random((hidden_dim, output_dim))

num_epochs = 10000
learning_rate = 1.0

for epoch_n in range(num_epochs):
    layer0 = X
    # Forward propagation.

    # Inside the perceptron, Step 2. 
    layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer0, W1))
    layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(layer1, W2))

    # Back propagation (Y -> layer2)

    # How much did we miss in the predictions?
    layer2_error = cost(layer2, Y)
    # In what direction is the target value?
    # Were we really close? If so, don't change too much.
    layer2_delta = layer2_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer2)


    # Back propagation (layer2 -> layer1)
    # How much did each layer1 value contribute to the layer2 error (according to the weights)?
    layer1_error = np.dot(layer2_delta, W2.T)
    layer1_delta = layer1_error * sigmoid_derivative(layer1)

    # update weights
    W2 +=  learning_rate * np.dot(layer1.T, layer2_delta)
    W1 +=  learning_rate * np.dot(layer0.T, layer1_delta)
```

We see that we've fully trained the network to memorize the outputs for XOR:

```
# On the training data
[int(prediction > 0.5) for prediction in layer2]
```

[out]:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

If we re-feed the same inputs, we get the same output:

```
for x, y in zip(X, Y):
    layer1_prediction = sigmoid(np.dot(W1.T, x)) # Feed the unseen input into trained W.
    prediction = layer2_prediction = sigmoid(np.dot(W2.T, layer1_prediction)) # Feed the unseen input into trained W.
    print(int(prediction > 0.5), y)
```

[out]:

```
0 [0]
1 [1]
1 [1]
0 [0]
```

But if we retrain the parameters (W1 and W2) without one of the data points, i.e.

```
xor_input = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
xor_output = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T
```

## Let's drop the last row of data and use that as unseen test.

```
X = xor_input[:-1]
Y = xor_output[:-1]
```

And with the rest of the same code, regardless of how I change the hyperparameters, it's un-able to learn the XOR function and reproduce the I/O.

```
for x, y in zip(xor_input, xor_output):
    layer1_prediction = sigmoid(np.dot(W1.T, x)) # Feed the unseen input into trained W.
    prediction = layer2_prediction = sigmoid(np.dot(W2.T, layer1_prediction)) # Feed the unseen input into trained W.
    print(int(prediction > 0.5), y)
```

[out]:

```
0 [0]
1 [1]
1 [1]
1 [0]
```

## Even if we shuffle the in-/output:

```
# Shuffle the order of the inputs
_temp = list(zip(X, Y))
random.shuffle(_temp)
xor_input_shuff, xor_output_shuff = map(np.array, zip(*_temp))
```

We can't train the XOR function fully:'

```
for x, y in zip(xor_input, xor_output):
    layer1_prediction = sigmoid(np.dot(W1.T, x)) # Feed the unseen input into trained W.
    prediction = layer2_prediction = sigmoid(np.dot(W2.T, layer1_prediction)) # Feed the unseen input into trained W.
    print(x, int(prediction > 0.5), y)
```

[out]:

```
[0 0] 1 [0]
[0 1] 1 [1]
[1 0] 1 [1]
[1 1] 0 [0]
```

So when the literature states that the multi-layered perceptron (Aka the basic deep learning) solves XOR, **does it mean that it can fully learn and memorize the weights given the fully set of in-/outputs but cannot generalize the XOR problem given that one of data point is missing?**

Here's the link of the Kaggle dataset that answerers can test the network for themselves: https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/xor-with-mlp/

Comment: Related thread on https://twitter.com/alvations/status/960323543425630208

Comment: I like yoav's points. It's kinda of impossible

Answer (score 1):

I think learning (generalizing) XOR and memorizing XOR are different things.

A two-layer perceptron can memorize XOR as you have seen, that is there exists a combination of weights where the loss is minimum and equal to 0 (absolute minimum).

If the weights are randomly initialized, you might end up with the situation where you have actually learned XOR and not only memorized.

Note that multi-layer perceptrons are non-convex functions so, there could be multiple minima (multiple global minima even). When data is missing one input, there are multiple minima (and all are equal in value) and there exists minima where the missing point would be correctly classified. Hence, MLP can learn an XOR. (though finding that weight combination might be hard with a missing point).

It is quite often argued that Neural Networks are universal function approximator and can approximate non-sense labels even. In that light, you might want to look at this work https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03530